# Move posts to top of WP_Query if in certain Taxonomy?

Tags: wp-query, loop, taxonomy

I'm trying to figure out the best way to promote certain (custom) posts to the top of my Wordpress loop. I can't use sticky posts because they are all in a custom post type.. I was thinking of using a taxonomy to do this, however I'm not sure if it will work, I am thinking I may need 2 loops?

Comment: Is it for the main query or a secondary query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is just a concept which you can try.*

By default, you cannot sort within the loop. You have, according to my knowledge, have two choices

- Create two loops and merging them. This, however, I would not recommend. Pagination and offsets are a nightmare if you are not completely comfortable with it
- Run your loop as normal, and pushing the results into two separate arrays, merging the two arrays and from there extract and display the posts. You can paginate as normal

Example bases on the main query with a custom post type and default post type set with `pre_get_posts`. You can also do this on any custom query. For a list of member variable variable that you can use, see [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post). *Note, this uses PHP 5.4 syntax*

```
$post_type_posts = []; //change to $post_type_posts = array(); for pre 5.4
$other_posts = []; //change to $other_posts = array(); for pre 5.4

if(have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) {
       the_post();

       if( 'my_post_type' == $wp_query->post_type ) {
          $post_type_posts[] = get_the_title();
       }else{
          $other_posts[] = get_the_title();
       }
     }
}

$new_loop = array_merge($post_type_posts, $other_posts);

foreach ($new_loop as $loop) {
   var_dump( $loop );
}
```

**EDIT**

Your idea will also work. Create a custom taxonomy, say `tax` and create two terms under the `tax` taxonomy, say `term-a` and `term-b`. OK, say `term-a` should display first.

Then alter the above code as follow:

```
$post_type_posts = []; //change to $post_type_posts = array(); for pre 5.4
$other_posts = []; //change to $other_posts = array(); for pre 5.4

if(have_posts()) {
    while(have_posts()) {
       the_post();

       if( has_term( 'term-a', 'tax' ) ) {
          $post_type_posts[] = get_the_title();
       }else{
          $other_posts[] = get_the_title();
       }
     }
}

$new_loop = array_merge($post_type_posts, $other_posts);

foreach ($new_loop as $loop) {
   var_dump( $loop );
}
```

**EDIT 2**

For a custom query using `tax_query`, you can use the following:

```
$args = [
'post_type' => 'my-post-type',
'tax_query' => [
        [
            'taxonomy' => 'tax',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => [ 'term-a', 'term-b' ],
        ]
    ]
];

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$post_type_posts = []; //change to $post_type_posts = array(); for pre 5.4
$other_posts = []; //change to $other_posts = array(); for pre 5.4

if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
       $query->the_post();

       if( has_term( 'term-a', 'tax' ) ) {
          $post_type_posts[] = get_the_title();
       }else{
          $other_posts[] = get_the_title();
       }
     }
}

wp_reset_postdata();

$new_loop = array_merge($post_type_posts, $other_posts);

foreach ($new_loop as $loop) {
   var_dump( $loop );
}
```

For more info, check [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: This is looking good but they are both the same post type. I can split them with taxonomies or custom fields though. Was thinking of 2 arrays; push into 1 if in taxonomy x otherwise push into the other.

Comment: Yes, you can do that as well, will update my answer

Comment: Is there a way to always show 5 posts from $post_type_posts[]?