# Pin posts to top of custom loop

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, loop, sticky-post

### Question

What would be the best way to pin certain posts to the beginning of a custom loop that queries for many custom post types and may or may not have tax queries inside?

Due to how the rest of the theme works, I would prefer if it could be handled in a single query (The process may use more than one query but at the end I'd prefer to have one final query that can be looped through).

SQL answers are welcome but please explain your answer to me as if I were a child, since I don't know much about how SQL works.

### Possibilities Considered

##### Sticky Posts

This is pretty much the functionality I required, but as most of you know it is not available for custom post types.

##### Meta Query

A very clean approach would be to have a meta query that uses a meta_key available in all of my posts called `is_pinned`. This meta_key would equal `0` for all posts by default and `1` for pinned posts. Then I could use `'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'` and `'order' => 'DESC'` in my query args.

However, I understand that post meta is not indexed and therefore my queries (which will be used to call a large number of posts) might take too long and affect site speed.

##### Merging Two Queries

Another approach I considered would be to make two queries, one for the pinned posts using `post__in` and another for the rest of the posts, ignoring the pinned posts by using `post__not_in` (neither of these would have pagination; `'posts_per_page'=>-1`) Then, I would merge the results of the two queries by doing something like this:

```
$final_query->posts = array_merge($pinned_query->posts, $unpinned_query->posts);
$final_query->post_count = count($final_query->posts);
$final_query->max_num_pages = ceil( $final_query->post_count/get_option( 'posts_per_page' ) );
//Not sure if this last line would work, have not tried it
```

However, I think this approach is a bit hacky. I worry that pagination might not work correctly.

##### Querying, Sorting and then Querying Again

This consists of first querying for all the posts I wish to display with pagination disabled: `'posts_per_page'=>-1`. Then, I loop through them, saving the IDs of all the ones with the tag 'pinned' into a `pinned_posts` array, and the rest into a `not_pinned_posts` array. Then I would append the latter to the former so the pinned posts IDs precede the rest of the post IDs. Finally I would run a new query that uses `post__in` equal to my sorted array and also `'orderby' => 'post__in'` so I can keep that sorted order. Something like this:

(partially modified from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161163/move-posts-to-top-of-wp-query-if-in-certain-taxonomy) )

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

$pinned_posts = array();
$not_pinned_posts = array();

if($query->have_posts()) {
    while($query->have_posts()) {
       $query->the_post();

       if( has_tag( 'pinned') ) {
          array_push( $pinned_posts, get_the_ID() );
       }else{
          array_push( $not_pinned_posts, get_the_ID() );
       }
     }
}

$sorted_posts = array_merge($pinned_posts, $not_pinned_posts);

wp_reset_postdata();


$args = array(
    'post__in' => $sorted_posts,
    'orderby' => 'post__in',
);

$final_query = new WP_Query( $args );

//Loop through the final query ...
```

This is the one I prefer at the moment since we don't mess with pagination so I should be able to paginate as normal. Also, I *think* it would be faster than the meta query. However, I don't really know how fast it will be since we're running through a large query twice.

Comment: Pagination does still come into play here if the first query is paginated - this would only display pinned posts from the current page. Do you intend to display all pinned posts above the rest?

Comment: You're right @bosco . In my head all of the examples I gave use ```'posts_per_page' => -1``` except the final query (the one I will use to display the post, which is the only one to be paginated). I'll edit the question to make that clear.